# WP_Query Ignoring `post_type` parameter

Tags: wp-query

```
<?php
    $args = array(
        'post_type'=>'weather_today',
        'orderby'=>'ID',
        'order'=>'ASC',
        'posts_per_page'=>1
    );
    $query = new WP_Query($args);
    if ($query->have_posts()) {
        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
            the_content();
        endwhile;
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Outputs a post content (`the_content()`) that is not of a `weather_today` type. Why is this? I checked my SQL, in `wp_posts` I only have *one* post of `post_type = "weather_today"` and it's not the one being outputted. This query is up in my header... and I believe above any other custom queries. Furthermore, it seems the other params are respected, the post I am getting is only `1` and is that last *regular post* by `ID`.

So why is the `post_type`, the most important param in this query, being ignored?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
<?php
    $args = array(
        'post_type'=>'weather_today',
        'orderby'=>'ID',
        'order'=>'ASC',
        'posts_per_page'=>1
    );
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();

        //loop 

    endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Comment: It makes no sense to use `wp_reset_query` in this code. You don't modify global `$wp_query` object... You have to use `wp_reset_postdata()` though...

Comment: oh yes. corrected

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is pretty simple... You use your custom `$query` in if statement, but then you use global `$wp_query` in while loop...

```
<?php
    $args = array(
        'post_type'=>'weather_today',
        'orderby'=>'ID',
        'order'=>'ASC',
        'posts_per_page'=>1
    );
    $query = new WP_Query($args);  // <- here you create custom $query
    if ($query->have_posts()) {  // <- here you check if it has any posts
        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); // <- here you don't use it
        // it should be:  while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
            the_content();
        endwhile;
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

PS. Another suggestion - don't use `{` and `:` notation in same context - it's bad for readability ;)